# Convert live audio stream into text while conferencing using WebRTC

Tags: node.js, webrtc, google-translate

I am implementing a system like video conferencing using WebRTC and NodeJS.
but i want to add some extra feature to it , suppose there is one moderator and 5 audiences who is asking question , so 1 is busy with 1 moderator , rest audiences record their questions ,which will be converted to text and will be shown on moderator's screen , so that based on that moderator can answer as per his requirement and leave unwanted questions. hope you can imagine the system.
first thing is , is it doable?
if yes , any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply try **Google Speech Recognition API**, same as [Traslator.js](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Translator/) do. Speech Recognition API can convert audio into text which can be further played as voice using either Google Translation API or meSpeak.js.

[RecordRTC.js](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) can be used only for wav/webm recordings. It is incapable to convert voice into text.

---

Updated at: 11:23 am -- Saturday, 7 June 2014 (UTC)

#### Personally I think Google Translation API is the only "Official" i.e. "non-free" API. Speech Recognition API is naively supported both on chrome and Firefox and it is part of some kind of specification, though submitted by Google developers.

*Web Speech API Specification:* https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html

Comment: Actualy Google Speech Recognition API seems to be paid API , thats why we are looking for alternative solution. but thnx for reply :-)

Comment: hi Muaz Khan,
in Web Speech API  does not supporting capture audio(audio capture failed event ) from mobile browsers, how do i solve this,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77938795/how-can-i-capture-audio-for-webrtc-applications-in-all-mobile-browsers-to-enable