# How can I capture audio for WebRTC applications in all mobile browsers to enable subtitles using Web Speech API?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, speech-recognition

I've implemented a WebRTC application that incorporates real-time subtitles generated from user audio using the Web Speech API speech recognition feature. While desktop browsers function smoothly, mobile browsers consistently encounter an "audio capture failed" error. Can someone guide achieving consistent audio capture functionality across all mobile browsers within my WebRTC application?

here is my code:-

```
let recognition;
let audioContext; 

let isRecognitionActive = false;

    // Function to create the AudioContext on user gesture
    function createAudioContext() {

        audioContext = localMediaAudioContext; // from my webrtc local audio context
        console.log('NewAudioContext',audioContext)
      }
// Function to initialize speech recognition
function initSpeechRecognition() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ) {

    recognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition)();
  recognition.lang = 'en-US';

  recognition.continuous = true;
  recognition.interimResults = true; // Set to false to improve recognition responsiveness

  recognition.onstart = function() {
    console.log('Speech recognition started');
    isRecognitionActive = true;
  };

  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    const transcript = event.results[event.results.length - 1][0].transcript; 


    sendSpeechTranscript(transcript);
  };

  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error('Speech recognition error:', event.error);
    if (event.error === 'no-speech') {
      console.log('No speech detected. Restarting recognition...');
      // Restart speech recognition when no speech is detected
      if (!isRecognitionActive) {
        recognition.start();
      }
    }
  };

  recognition.onend = function() {
    console.log('Speech recognition ended');
    // Set recognition active to false when recognition ends
    isRecognitionActive = false;
    // Continue speech recognition indefinitely
    if (!isRecognitionActive) {
      recognition.start();
    }
  };

}
}


// Function to send speech transcript over WebRTC
function sendSpeechTranscript(transcript) {
  // Implement your logic to send the transcript over WebRTC
  console.log('Sending transcript over WebRTC:', transcript);
 
  var data;
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#transcript').text('You : ' + transcript);
  }, 2000);
  // $('#recognized-text').text('You : ' + transcript);

    if(transcript){
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#transcript').text('');
      }, 6000);
    }

}

// Call the initSpeechRecognition function to initialize speech recognition
    initSpeechRecognition();

// Attach click event listener to start speech recognition when #idCaption is clicked
$('#CaptionClickevent').on('click', function(){
    // Start speech recognition if not already active
    if (!isRecognitionActive) {
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       if (!audioContext) {
        createAudioContext();
      }
      recognition.start();
          console.log('start recognition');
    }


});
```

Comment: I have discovered that when using the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` command to obtain the media stream on a mobile device, 
the SpeechRecognition object fails to recognize speech.

However, when solely utilizing the SpeechRecognition object without invoking the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` command to obtain the media stream, 
it functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can study how the getUserMedia method will behave on mobile device browsers. After all, mobile device browsers are different from computer browsers.